# Dynamically define structs from JSON file in Go

Tags: json, go, struct

I want to dynamically define structs in a Go project based on a JSON file.

For example, if I had a json file like so...

```
{
  "date": "today",
  "time": 12,
  "era": "never",
  "alive": true
}
```

Then I would expect a struct to be generated (that would look) like this (but not explicitly defined in the source code)...

```
type DynamicJSON struct {
  date, era string
  time int
  alive bool
}
```

Furthermore, I want to nest JSON objects such that I could do something like this...

```
{
  "date": "today",
  "time": 12,
  "era": "never",
  "alive": true,
  "nested": {
    "date": "tomorrow",
    "alive": true
  }
}
```

...which would actually generate two different structs, like this...

```
type DynamicJSON1 struct {
      date, era string
      time int
      alive bool
}


type DynamicJSON2 struct {
      date string
      alive bool
}
```

Is this something that is currently supported?

Comment: I believe you cannot dynamically, at runtime, define types in Go. The next best option would be to use code generation.

Comment: What result do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you really unstructured data you can unmarshal it into maps like `map[string]interface{}`

Answer (score 2):

I can't garantantee final result, but [easyjson](https://github.com/mailru/easyjson) does exactly what you asking.

> easyjson aims to keep generated Go code simple enough so that it can
>   be easily optimized or fixed. Another goal is to provide users with
>   the ability to customize the generated code by providing options not
>   available with the standard encoding/json package, such as generating
>   "snake_case" names or enabling omitempty behavior by default.

Comment: @kendall-weihe, for one-off gigs, you can use [`github.com/mholt/json-to-go`](https://github.com/mholt/json-to-go), which also has a readily working site which would generate a set of Go types from the JSON samples you throw at it.